# Counting occurrences of word in vector of characters

Tags: c++

I have written a program to store a text file in vector of characters .

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<char> vec;
    ifstream file("text.txt");

    if(!file.eof() && !file.fail())
    {
        file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
        std::streampos fileSize = file.tellg();
        vec.resize(fileSize);

        file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
        file.read(&vec[0], fileSize);
    }

    int c = count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 'U');
    cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to count occurrence of  "USER" in the text file , but using count i can only count number of characters . How can i count number of occurrences of  "USER" in the vector of character?

For example 
text.txt

```
USERABRUSER#$$* 34 USER ABC RR IERUSER
```

Then the count of "USER" is 4. Words can only be in uppercase.

Comment: Define what you mean by "word".  Also, your IO isn't quite right: it's more idiomatic to test with `file.is_open()` after open; more importantly, `file.read` will likely fail, since the way you calculate the size won't work on non-Unix platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::string` has a `find` member function that will find an occurrence of one string inside another. You can use that to count occurrences something like this:

```
size_t count(std::string const &haystack, std::string const &needle) {
    auto occurrences = 0;
    auto len = needle.size();
    auto pos = 0;

    while (std::string::npos != (pos = haystack.find(needle, pos))) {
        ++occurrences;
        pos += len;
    }
    return occurrences;
}
```

For example:

```
int main() {
    std::string input{ "USERABRUSER#$$* 34 USER ABC RR IERUSER" };

    std::cout << count(input, "USER");
}
```

...produces an output of `4`.

Comment: This solves the problem , but i have been suggested to use vector of characters and count function ....But thanks anyway...

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   unordered_map<string, size_t> data;
   string line;
   ifstream file("text.txt");
   while (getline(file, line)) {
      istringstream is(line);
      string word;
      while (is >> word) {
        ++data[word];
      }
   }

   cout << data["USER"] << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although this (at least arguably) fit the question as originally posted, it doesn't fit the edited question. Either way, it's potentially quite inefficient, storing a great deal of data for which it has no real use. It's roughly equivalent to answering: "how many children are in this teacher's class?" by taking a census of the entire country, then checking how many of those people are in the class in question.

Comment: Your analogy is wrong. I don't increase the data size that needs to be processed. We both process the same amount of data (i.e. the file), I, however, do more work per item than you do.  My solution allows answering additional questions easier and is a more generic solution. Might not add any value to OP but could be useful to others who are trying to answer a similar problem and need to query the processed dataset for more than one word. In anycase, if OP doesn't want to store the results in a unordered_map, he/she can remove the functionality and go on his/her business.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try again. Once again, a vector isn't necessary. This is what I would consider to be the most C++ idiomatic way. It uses `std::string`'s `find()` method to repeatedly find the substring in order until the end of the string is reached.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    // Read entire file into a single string.
    std::ifstream file_stream("text.txt");
    std::string file_contents(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file_stream),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    unsigned count = 0;
    std::string substr = "USER";
    for (size_t i = file_contents.find(substr); i != std::string::npos;
        i = str.find(substr, i + substr.length())) {
        ++count;
    }
}
```