# How to read a string for a specific word and count the times it was found

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to write a program to check a txt file to find a specific word, ranger, and count it.
Once everything is counted, I need to print it the total count of rangers and the total count of strings. I have no clue how to do this though.

I am almost failing c++, and really need this help.  This is what I have came up with so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;


int main() {
  string ranger[50]; 
    ifstream rangerin("Ranger.txt");


    if ( !rangerin ) {
        cout << "Invalid File\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    string message;

    while ( getline(rangerin, message) ) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [another recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29991079/179910).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following strategy.

1. Read the file word by word in a loop.
2. Compare every word you read with the word you are looking for.
3. If they are same, increment the count.
4. When you are finished reading, exit the loop.
5. Print the count.

```
int main()
{
   int count = 0;
   std::ifstream rangerin("Ranger.txt");

   if ( !rangerin ) {
      cout << "Invalid File\n";
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   std::string word;
   while ( rangerin >> word  )
   {
      // This needs to be modified if case insensitive comparison
      // is expected.
      if ( word == "ranger" )
      {
         ++count;
      }
   }

   std::cout << "Number of times 'ranger' was found: " << count << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

**Edit**

The trouble with the above approach is that if you have `ranger,` in your file, that won't be counted. That means the comparison has to be refined a little bit.

Write a function `isWordRanger` and hide the details in that function.

```
bool isWordRanger(string const& word)
{
    // Add additional refined checks as needed.
    return ( (word == "ranger") ||
             (word == "ragner,") ||
             (word == "ranger.") );
}
```

and change `main` to use:

```
      if ( isWordRanger(word) )
      {
         ++count;
      }
```

Comment: It gives me the number 00x47d748

Comment: Why such the weird number?

Comment: @deadpirateroberts, really? I am surprised. Make sure you didn't use `<< cout` instead of `<< count`.

Comment: @deadpirateroberts, I had made the exact same mistake that I though you might have made. Instead of `std::endl`, I had used `std::cout`. Fixed the answer.

Comment: Hm, What could I be doing wrong on my side to give me the count of 0 now? I have the exact code, and a valid file.

Comment: @deadpirateroberts, see my update. Hopefully that gives you some idea on how to fix your problem.

Comment: Just added my problem.  Getting Errors, New to c++ in gen

Comment: The forward declaration needs to be `bool isWordRanger(string const&);`, not `bool isWordRanger(string);`

Comment: see the problem one sec

Comment: Nope, still putting out 0.